# CSS Dropdown Menu, Parent not clickable

Tags: html, css

I have created a [CSS fly out menu](http://jsfiddle.net/JsVr4/). 
Seems to fly out the submenu on hover, Which is what I need.
The only problem I have is when the li a has a submenu, You cant click on the Top level menu item. I can see in Firebug that it is overlaying over the top.

Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you giv the submenu ul a minus z-index this will fix your problem.

```
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    z-index: -1;
    }
```

Here is the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JsVr4/3/

**EDIT**

After viewing the site I have made a change to my answer.

Start by changing the following in your `#nav ul ul li` from

```
#nav ul ul li {
    top: 42px;
    }
```

to

```
#nav ul ul li {
    top: 0px;
    }
```

then add the following to the `#nav ul ul`

```
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 32px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    }
```

This will solve the problem. The `#nav ul ul` was positioned above the a tag which was causing the problem.

Comment: I am unable to do that. The site I'm working on has a jQuery scrolling menu so that needs a higher Z-Index : Site is : http://www.hope-foundation.org.uk 

Thanks

Comment: Hi Stu, I have edited my answer to fix your problem. Hopefully it works ok for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to the way you've given a 'top' property to your li tags. Simply removing that property and instead putting it in the nested unordered list tag will help a lot (like below) since otherwise your sub-menu is overlapping your menu.

```
#nav ul ul {
  left: 0;
  list-style: none outside none;
  padding:0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px; /* this is what I added */
}
```

I did my own version of what you have in jsfiddle. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/akiryk/EJ8u2/2/

Also, I'd recommend spending a little time reviewing some useful tutorials on the basics of using css and lists.

A good old one from alistapart: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/horizdropdowns/